# Magento2 : Manage to currency format in multi language website

Tags: magento2

I have two language website like Arabic and English in which currency format is not matching in both store.If product has price 14,751.89 $ then it have show Like this because of Arabic language.

> AR Store : الهندي SAR
>
> En Store : $ 14 751,89

But I need to show like

> AR Store : 14 751,89 SAR
>
> En Store : $ 14 751,89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Install this extension >> https://github.com/magento1994/CurrencyTools
>
> After that you can manage it through admin.
>
> Give the currency symbol and direction
>
> **Note** : Modify extension as per your Vendor_Module.

Path of setting : Store > Config > General > Currency Setup > Currency Position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We Have Multiple Language Store English And Arabic So We Provide Both Language So The Arabic Language Font Family Can Apply To Both Number language Arabic And English But We can Need All Number Are Show Only English Language.

In That Solution Is You Can Remove The Fon-Family of Arabic Language For All Number Format.

In That The Problem Is That The All Number Format Font-family Used By Arabic So the All Number are Translate In Arabic Language.

Comment: that the perfect answer

Comment: hi jay.. can you please help me how can we do that ?
I have same issue for my store

Comment: I have the same issue. how can we remove the font family for the number format in the Arabic store?